# nginx configuration works over curl, but not in browser?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, load-balancing

I have an nginx configuration resembling something like this:

```
# mysite.com nginx config
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /usr/share/mysite.com/ui;
        index index.html;
        server_name lbhost;

        location /ads.txt { 
            alias /usr/share/mysite.com/ads.txt; 
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass       http://localhost:5000/api/;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        }
}
```

The load-balanced servers have a .NET Core web api and an Angular Universal UI.  This seems to work pretty well, but

... the api proxy seems to work, as does the root paths, and (usually) the ads.txt file as well, but... if I do something like

```
ubuntu@my-host-name:~$ curl http://localhost/api/version
```

...from the local machine, I'll get a response like:

```
2020.5.13.4ubuntu@my-host-name:~$
```

... yet if I hit this endpoint from a browser, I get a completely empty page... even the source is empty.  I would expect to see that text "2020.5.13.4" in the source document of the page at least.

How do I need to configure my nginx service to properly send responses?

**UPDATE**

Per request, here is the response with headers:

```
ubuntu@my-host-name:~$ curl -i http://localhost/api/version
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 21 May 2020 17:00:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

2020.5.13.4ubuntu@my-host-name:~$
```

also, the access log reports as follows:

```
ip source redacted - - [21/May/2020:11:02:20 +0000] "GET /api/version HTTP/1.1" 200 21 "-" "curl/7.58.0"
ip source redacted - - [21/May/2020:11:04:05 +0000] "GET /api/version HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: do you have an index.html file in /usr/share/mysite.com/ui?  It looks as though curl may be retrieving the logged in command line prompt from the server, but to a browser, even if it received that it wouldn't know what to do with it.  Try sticking a simple "Hello World" web page at ```/usr/share/mysite.com/ui/index.html``` if there's not a file already there, and see what happens.

Comment: It may be interesting to see the response headers, particularly the Content-Type. Try: `curl -i http://localhost/api/version`

Comment: Also, what are the two access log entries, for the document fetched using `curl` and the same URL using the browser?

Comment: there is an index.html file, compiled from the Angular code.  I'll take a look at the header information and update the post, and see what's available for the access log entries as well.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your web application, not your web server configuration.

Comment: hmmmm, system has large, complicated, custom, component and simple, off-the-shelf, widely-used component. System is not behaving as expected. Assumed that fault is in simple, off-the-shelf component.

Answer (score 0):

Check your UFW or firewall configuration.

I had an issue with UFW having the HTTP but not the HTTPS rule, curl was able to get the index.html entry but not on browser or postman.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the issue using https instead of the http.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this because I was redirecting to HTTPS but I did not have my encryption certificates.

Once I added the certs using certbot, I was able to serve my index pages.

I used this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).